# Botbuilder-Js SDK is not picking up the Secret keys from appsettings.json exported by Bot composer

Tags: typescript, botframework

Issue: - we are using bot builder-JS SDK with version 4.11.0 . We are taking the bot files from the bot composer and trying to run bot with that files. We integrated the files and able to run the bot but when we are using luis it is asking for the secret keys and we are passing it through expression as we get from the bot composer but it was unable to get the keys.

When we checked in the bot composer folder the folder structure is like this
[[image: File structure from bot composer]

From here we have `. dialog file` for every parent and child dialogs in recognizer folder and there is `appsettings.json` and `luis.settings.composer.westus.json` file.

The content in the dialog file will be like this, there are expressions to get the keys

```
{ 

  "$kind": "Microsoft.LuisRecognizer", 

  "id": "LUIS_additem", 

  "applicationId": "=settings.luis.additem_en_us_lu.appId", 

  "version": "=settings.luis.additem_en_us_lu.version", 

  "endpoint": "=settings.luis.endpoint", 

  "endpointKey": "=settings.luis.endpointKey" 

}
```

So, we kept the secret keys in  **appsettings.json** file as well as in **luis.settings.composer.westus.json** file but when we run the bot it is unable to get the keys from the json files and getting error that application ID of undefined for luis

[image: Emulator log]

Solutions we tried

We removed the expression in the `.dialog file` and placed the secret keys in the file bot working fine.

Our question

is there any function in botbuilder-js SDK that it will take the settings from the appsettings.json file? Or is there any way to set the settings so that when the bot runs it will take from the appsettings.json or .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Just circling back on this. Per this [discussion here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/3152#issuecomment-771386838), you will need to modify the bot to load settings from more than just appsettings.json.

Basically:

- Load settings via getSettings(projectRoot): e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/blob/73c0bcecc04cf809838fc23870cb5613722fcd22/runtime/node/src/shared/composerBot.ts#L54
- Set settings to your dialog manager's initial state with correct key settings: e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/blob/73c0bcecc04cf809838fc23870cb5613722fcd22/runtime/node/src/shared/composerBot.ts#L94